# How can I set a ringtone for an individual contact on Android?

Tags: android, contacts, addressbook, ringtone

How can I apply a ringtone to only the selected contact?

I have found a way to set the default ringtone that applies to all contacts, but that is not my goal.

I want an application to have a button ("Apply ringtone to contact") that, when clicked, starts an `activityForResult` displaying a list of all contacts on the phone. When a contact is selected, the contact activity closes and returns with a URI to the contact. Then the app needs to apply the selected ringtone to that specific contact.

The code for displaying and selecting contacts by an activity is already implemented and seems to work on the app.

Comment: android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns has CUSTOM_RINGTONE for ringtone URI, so it should be possible to update selected contact with CUSTOM_RINGTONE for selected ringtone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [ContactsContract.Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) which has a column `CUSTOM_RINGTONE` (which is a read/write column!) for this purpose.

```
Uri contactUri;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, 
    newRingtoneUri.toString());
context.getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, where, args);
```

Furthermore, you may find [this discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg63837.html) useful (code taken from there).

Comment: Thanks, That was a very helpful discussion. Lot's of frustrated developers about the lack of documentation and examples from Google. I'll give your pasted code a try. Hopefully to work on 1.5 -> 2.1 ... At the moment the current code the app is using only works for 1.5 and 1.6, not for 2.0 or 2.1... E.g it works for Magic, Hero and G1, but not for DROID or Nexus

Comment: Vidar Vestnes Could you please post the final code to set the ringtone to the contact. I not sure how to get and provide the URL of a Music file to the "ContentValues".

Comment: does my ringtone extension should always be ogg or I can use mp3 extension as well ??

Comment: and how did you get your contact URI please ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was so late, but i'm posting here because above one not worked for me

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test/ArjunMovieTelugu.mp3");
    if(file.exists()) {

        Uri oldUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
        resolver.delete(oldUri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);


        String contact_number = "CONTACT_NUMBER";
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, contact_number);

        // The columns used for `Contacts.getLookupUri`
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
        };

        Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {
            data.moveToFirst();
            // Get the contact lookup Uri
            long contactId = data.getLong(0);
            String lookupKey = data.getString(1);
            Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);

            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Beautiful");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri newUri = resolver.insert(uri, values);

            if(newUri != null){
                String uriString = newUri.toString();
                values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, uriString);
                Log.e("Uri String for " + ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, uriString);
                long updated = resolver.update(contactUri, values,null, null);

                Toast.makeText(RingtoneChange.this, "Updated : " + updated, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            data.close();
        }


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(RingtoneChange.this, "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Note:** We have to add runtime permissions for marsh mallow as

```
int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
int readExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
int writeExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
int readContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
int writeContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);

List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

if (readExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
if (writeExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
if (readContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

}
if (writeContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);

}

if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
            (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

and also include all these permissions in Manifest file as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```