# Android - How to set the contact ringtone programmatically?

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a ringtone for an individual contact on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437922/how-can-i-set-a-ringtone-for-an-individual-contact-on-android)

I am working on sample application on contacts where I can add the contacts in my android app and I can sync the contact at anytime to android native contacts(Address book). I am able to insert the contacts to native contacts now. Only thing is i am not able to set the contact ringtone. Contact ring tone is saved in my DB for all the contacts. But I am struggling to set the ring tone for individual contact. How can i achieve this. Below is the code for saving the  contacts. Currently i  am hardcoding everything.

```
    String DisplayName = "XYZ";
    String MobileNumber = "0000000000";
    String HomeNumber = "1111";
    String WorkNumber = "2222";
    String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
    String company = "xxxx";
    String jobTitle = "abcd";
    String Ringtonepath= "content://media/internal/audio/media/43";
    Uri Ringtone1 = Uri.parse(Ringtonepath);   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();


        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build()
        );

        //------------------------------------------------------ Names
        if(DisplayName != null)
        {          
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).
                    withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0).
                    withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).
                    withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,DisplayName)
                    .build());
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number                     
        if(MobileNumber != null)
        {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build()
            );
        }


        //------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
        if(HomeNumber != null)
        {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
        if(WorkNumber != null)
        {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------ Email
        if(emailID != null)
        {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());
        }



        //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
        if(!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals(""))
        {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)

                    .build());
        }

        // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                 
        try
        {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {              
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 




    }
}
```

How can i set the ringtone programmatically.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2438098/645270)

Comment: @Keyser In that link he is using update.... i need how to insert first time itself.

Comment: Are you getting some error if you try to insert the ringtone data? The field is already there, it just needs to be properly set. Maybe run an update after the insert?...(I'm out of ideas)

Comment: Yes... Exception contact Not inserted. If i try to save the contact using ringtone.

Comment: @keyser, thats a automated message when i cast a close vote

Comment: @nandeesh Heh I had no idea :) Non-privileged and all