# Get custom ringtone path of contact Android

Tags: android, android-contacts, ringtone

How can I retrieve the current custom ringtone path assigned to a contact with Android? Are they all stored in a special folder?

```
ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I need the actual sound file in a byte array or something similiar.

Comment: Do you want the name/reference or the actual sound file?

Comment: May help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40916383/5791681

Comment: The acutal sound file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like a normal field. To get the path I had to do:

```
int customRingtoneIndex = contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE);
String customRingtone = contactCursor.getString(customRingtoneIndex);
```

That returns the path to the actual content e.g. `content://media/internal/audio/media/162`